# c++ alias for anonymous c type

Tags: c++

I am keen to minimise dependency on a third-party header ([kiss_fft.h](http://kissfft.hg.sourceforge.net/hgweb/kissfft/kissfft/file/b354a59534b0/kiss_fft.h)). There is an *anonymous struct* defined within the header and I would really like to use my own *alias* (or some vague equivalent) interchangeably in my code.

The external definition that I oughtn't change:

```
typedef struct {
    float r;
    float i;
} kiss_fft_cpx;
```

My first attempt:

```
typedef kiss_fft_cpx FTBuffer;
// yields error: 'kiss_fft_cpx' does not name a type
```

My second attempt:

```
struct FTBuffer : public kiss_fft_cpx {};
// yields error: expected class-name before '{' token
```

I suppose my problem is that **kiss_fft_cpx** is a variable and not a type, but perhaps there's a workaround you know of...?

I have searched for solutions here, and on the wider web, but nothing is jumping out. I am hoping that this is just a gap in my knowledge, but accept that there may be no advisable solution. Optimistic thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using a compiler that supports C++11 features like `decltype`?

Comment: `kiss_fft_cpx` is a type name that should be usable as a base class and for `typedef`s. [Example.](http://liveworkspace.org/code/04fe7d6c236d4f9e59029b8440048885)

Comment: works without a problem in VC++ 2010

Comment: @BjörnPollex That sounds ideal. I'm not sure if it supports C+11, but am using GCC 4.6.2. I am trying to save C++11 until I am more competent with the current version and can really appreciate the improvements!

Comment: `kiss_fft_cpx` is not a variable, it's a typedefed type. Your code is just fine, (see [example](http://ideone.com/6mA6h))... I think your problem originates elsewhere; maybe you didn't include the header file containing `kiss_fft_cpx` properly?

Comment: @Xeo et al Thanks so much for the examples (http://liveworkspace.org and http://ideone.com are neat!), I will pick my code apart to see what's different.

Comment: @EitanT Rookie error! The include was in my source file and not my header. Thank you very much.

Comment: someone ought to add what worked as an answer

Comment: @GeoffReedy It's unlikely to help anybody else as its a very localised problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef struct {
    float r;
    float i;
} kiss_fft_cpx;

typedef kiss_fft_cpx FTBuffer;

int main()
{}
```

Works fine both as C++ and as C, so the problem is something else you do (or rather, don't do).

Comment: I suppose credit ought to go to EitanT, who put their finger right on my specific rookie error, but thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: @mosi: for questions of this nature there's no credit to be had. i just think (thought) the question ought to be answered. and no, it's not a given that such code will work fine also as C, although it does in this particular case.